# How to prevent screenreader from announcing the number of DOM nodes when using JSX expressions?

Tags: reactjs, dom, accessibility, jsx, screen-readers

I am working on the screenreader accessibility of my ReactJS app and have been testing using VoiceOver.

I have a piece of text that visually says "Hi James!"

The JSX looks like this:

`<h1 tabindex="-1">Hi {name}!</h1>`

The problem is that VoiceOver announces this element like so:
"Heading level 1 3 items, Hi James!"

It's saying "3 items" because the rendered HTML contains 3 separate text nodes in the DOM:
[image: DOM]

I can change the JSX to a template literal to solve the issue but it makes the code unnecessarily verbose:

`` <h1 tabindex="-1">{`Hi ${name}!`}</h1> ``

Is there a cleaner way to solve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a VoiceOver issue. VoiceOver on Mac is quite a... particular screen reader, so to say. Have you tested it anywhere else?

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily an issue with just mac VoiceOver, it looks to be doing exactly by design, there are 3 "items"  in the h1.

Comment: VoiceOver is correct; JSX should not be putting three text nodes in the H1

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in React's JSX engine. For fun, try doing this:

```
<p>{new String(`Hi ${name}!`)}</p>
```

Your solution is probably the best. It only adds 4 bytes.
You can also do what I show above but omit the `new` keyword, to get a single `string` which will become a single text node.